# Ajax callbacks in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 2 for a ajax form we can have ajax callbacks like before, after etc. How to do it in rails 3.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, and [this post](http://blancer.com/tutorials/105318/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) helped me figure it out. Basically you need to attach a listener to the element that reacts on rails' callback events. For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post, 
  :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 
  :method => :delete, 
  :remote=>true, 
  :id=>'delete' %>
```

In a separate js file (to make it unobtrusive), with jQuery:

```
$('#delete').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks morbaq, I had also found it after googling around. But I thought there might be some rails way.

Comment: Rails 3 has gone away from "inline javascript" helpers like link_to_remote and moves towards Unobtrusive JavaScript (UJS), which you need to handle that way. AFAIK, the above code is in fact the 'rails way' since version 3.

Answer (score 1):

Binding a function to ajax:success as morbaq suggested worked for me.

However, I think if there is more than one ajax behavior associated with the element, the function will run for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

In case you also want to add listener for ajax send use following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#topnav-buildings').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
    blockDiv('#topnav-buildings');
  });
});
```

I spent an hour to find these t2 things

1. we have to put it inside document.ready
2. S is in caps when you write ajax:beforeSend
3. Dont use ajaxSend instead of ajax:beforeSend .... beacause it adds global handler for all ajax events