# Send Rails PUT request through javascript

Tags: javascript, controller, ruby-on-rails-3, action, put

How would I go about sending a PUT request to an action through javascript in Rails? Here's how I do it in the .html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to "Check", check_task_path(task), :method => :put %>
```

How would I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:remote => true` to enable ajax on the link.

```
<%= link_to "Check", check_task_path(task), :method => :put, :remote => true %>
```

Assuming you want a check tasks in `index` page.

### index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.name %></td>
    <td id="completed_<%= task.id %>"><%= task.completed %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 
            :method => :delete %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Check", check_task_path(task), :method => :put, 
            :remote => true, :class => :check_task %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

### tasks_controller.rb

```
  def check
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.completed = true
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        format.html { redirect_to(@task, 
         :notice => 'Task was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.js  
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, 
           :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
```

### check.erb.js

```
<% if @task.errors.empty? %>
  jQuery("#completed_<%= @task.id %>").html("true.");    
<% else %>
  alert("Task could not be saved.");
<% end %>
```

### routes.rb

```
  resources :tasks do
    member do
      put 'check'
    end
  end
```

### application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tada</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, well how do I send any (POST or GET) request to a controller action with javascript?

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263719/ajax-callbacks-in-rails3

Comment: Ok, but I'm trying to do it just in javascript, when the user clicks a checkbox (Hence the check function for a task). How do I do that?